# Setting left position of an element that changes dynamically(in a loop)

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript code.
    ***

> var pos = document.getElementById('pos'); 
>       pos.style.position = 'relative'; 
>       pos.style.width = '100%'; 
>       pos.style.height = '100%'; 
>       pos.style.background = 'gray'; 
>       for(i=1;i<4;i++) 
>       { 
>       var div = document.createElement('div'); 
>       var node = document.createTextNode("This is new."); 
>       div.appendChild(node); 
>       var j = i-1;
>       var f = Math.round(250/(i+1)); 
>       var d = Math.round(250/i); 
>       var col = 'rgb('+f+','+140+','+d+')'; 
>       div.style.background = col; 
>       div.style.width = '200px'; 
>       div.style.height = '300px'; 
>       div.style.position = 'relative'; 
>       div.style.top = '0px'; 
>       div.style.border = 'solid'; 
>       div.style.borderColor = 'green'; 
>       div.style.borderWidth = '2px'; 
>       left = Math.floor((j*200)+30+30); 
>       left = left+'px'; 
>       div.style.left = '30px'; 
>       pos.appendChild(div); 
>       }

---

HTML code:
      ***

> <div id = "pos"></div>

---

The first element is positioned correctly with 0px top and 30px left however the second and third are off the mark, I tried to use display as inline but that only set them on same line but the left positioning were not set. The result is 
[as shown in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CYFf.png)

[But I would like it to appear as:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXf0u.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `display:inline-block` and put some `margin-right:10px` to the dynamically created elements

Here is the edited code:

```
var pos = document.getElementById('pos');
     pos.style.position = 'relative';
     pos.style.width = '100%';
     pos.style.height = '100%';
     pos.style.background = 'gray';
     for(i=1;i<4;i++)
     {
     var div = document.createElement('div');
     var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
     div.appendChild(node);
     var j = i-1;
     var f = Math.round(250/(i+1));
     var d = Math.round(250/i);
     var col = 'rgb('+f+','+140+','+d+')';
     div.style.background = col;
     div.style.width = '200px';
     div.style.height = '300px';
     div.style.position = 'relative';
     div.style.display="inline-block"; //add this line
     div.style.marginRight="10px";     //add this line
     div.style.top = '0px';
     div.style.border = 'solid';
     div.style.borderColor = 'green';
     div.style.borderWidth = '2px';
     left = Math.floor((j*200)+30+30);
     left = left+'px';
     div.style.left = '30px';
     pos.appendChild(div);
     }
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pqjjm4m/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var pos = document.getElementById('pos');
     pos.style.position = 'relative';
     pos.style.width = '100%';
     pos.style.height = '100%';
     pos.style.background = 'gray';
     for(i=1;i<4;i++)
     {
     var div = document.createElement('div');
     var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
     div.appendChild(node);
     var j = i-1;
     var f = Math.round(250/(i+1));
     var d = Math.round(250/i);
     var col = 'rgb('+f+','+140+','+d+')';
     div.style.background = col;
     div.style.width = '200px';
     div.style.height = '300px';
     div.style.position = 'relative';
     div.style.display = 'inline-block';  //added 
     div.style.marginLeft = '1%';       //added
     div.style.top = '0px';
     div.style.border = 'solid';
     div.style.borderColor = 'green';
     div.style.borderWidth = '2px';
     left = Math.floor((j*200)+30+30);
     left = left+'px';
     div.style.left = '30px';
     pos.appendChild(div);
     }
```

Make display of each div to inline-block and give them a margin that will do 
[Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/6aqrv8Lv/)

Comment: Both answers above return the display as asked but my problem is how to make sure the left and top are set correctly without using the margin since my code depends on a number that changes from time to time and we set the created object from center depending with the number of objects created, and therefore each element wont be on the same each time

Comment: for that we should set width in percentage